# How to make 1 query to 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlite

I need to make one query resulting to a one column result from Recipe, Ingredients and Methods Table. My Example Tables:

I am getting the Recipe Name, Recipe Contributor, Recipe Description,
Ingredients for a recipe as well for its methods

Recipe Table

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
|RECIPE ID  | RECIPE NAME  | RECIPE CONTRIBUTOR | RECIPE DESCRIPTION |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1         |Chicken Curry | Me                 | Spicy and Hot      |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Ingredients Table

```
+----------------------------------+
|ING ID  | ING NAME    | RECIPE ID | 
------------------------------------
|1       |Chicken      | 1         |
------------------------------------
|2       |Curry Powder | 1         |
+----------------------------------+
```

Methods Table

```
+----------------------------------+
|MET ID  | METHOD      | RECIPE ID | 
------------------------------------
|1       |Boil Chicken | 1         |
------------------------------------
|2       |Cook curry   | 1         |
+----------------------------------+
```

Desired Output:

```
+---------------+
|Output Column  |
-----------------
 Chicken Curry
 Me
 Spicy and Hot
 Chicken
 Curry Powder
 Boil Chicken
 Cook curry
+----------------+
```

Comment: You just need to join the tables

Comment: This sounds like an interesting project, do let us know if you have a question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood you want to combine different columns from different tables into a single column output in order to use it in your Android app (previously the question had android tag). Below find my solution:

```
String query = 
"select \"RECIPE NAME\" AS output from Recipe
union all
select \"RECIPE CONTRIBUTOR\" from Recipe
union all
select \"RECIPE DESCRIPTION\" from Recipe
union all
select \"ING NAME\" from Ingredients
union all
select METHOD from Methods";

Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query, null);
```

Then iterate over the cursor with `cursor.getString(0);` to retrieve each row

Answer (score -1):

First of all you should not use whitespaces in columns. But a query would look something like:

```
SELECT "r.RECIPE NAME", "r.RECIPE CONTRIBUTER", "r.RECIPE DESCRIPTION", "i.ING NAME", "m.METHOD" 
FROM Recipe AS r INNER JOIN Ingridients AS i ON "r.RECIPE ID" = "i.RECIPE ID" INNER JOIN Methods AS m ON "r.RECIPE ID" = "m.RECIPE ID" 
WHERE "r.RECIPE ID" = 1
```

The double quotes around the selects etc are because of the whitespace in the column name, if you change your database to have columns with ex: RECIPE CONTRIBUTER = RECIPE_CONTRIBUTER you could just do r.RECIPE_CONTRIBUTER without the double quotes around.